# Plugin admob to NativeScript

Tags: admob, nativescript

I have tried to use NativeAdmob plugin on a simple NativeScript app, but this plugin has some bugs on 1.4 version. Is there another Admob Plugin to NativeScript?

https://github.com/alejonext/NativeAdmob

Comment: The first is that this library is experimental, it became just came nativescript. It is not good to use it in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Note that this was downvoted because it previously only contained a link, that's when the plugin was not yet finished as well - it's ready for production now!)*

I've implemented an AdMob plugin for AdMob. You can easily add it to your NativeScript project. It requires {N} 1.5.

Usage is like this:

```
admob.createBanner({
  size: admob.AD_SIZE.SMART_BANNER
  iosBannerId: "ca-app-pub-XXXXXX/YYYYYY",
  androidBannerId: "ca-app-pub-AAAAAAAA/BBBBBBB",
  margins: {
    bottom: 50
  }
})
```

You can find the plugin [on npm, here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-admob).

Answer (score -1):

Nativescript is on the road for a year, but still now there is no Admob solution to it. [This library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-plugin-google-play-services) implements Google Play Services to NativeScript, but I was not able to implement Admob directly.